# Can anyone explain why I can't concatenate these two matrices?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Here is my matrices and codeline:

```
d = np.array([[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[11,12,13],
       [16,17,18]])
e = np.array([[ 4,  5],[ 9, 10],[14, 15],[19, 20]])
np.concatenate(d,e)
```

and this is the error that I get:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax mistake in `np.concatenate(d,e)`, the syntax requires `d` and `e` to be in a tuple, like: `np.concatenate((d,e))`. I tested it, and `axis=1` is also required for it to work.

```py
np.concatenate((d, e), axis=1)
```

is the solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that they need to be in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Since those arrays have different dimensions you should specify the axis concatenate you what like the follow:
1)    `np.concatenate((d,e), axis=1)`

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

or 
2)`np.concatenate((d,e), axis=None)`

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18,  4,  5,  9, 10, 14,
       15, 19, 20])
```

Comment: Yeah your answer is much more complete, have you used numpy before? I looked up the docs for <5 minutes and tested my solution only with these arrays by copy&pasting

Comment: Yes, I was using pandas for a long time and by that, I was getting my numpy education.